# Redirect to undefined link after authentication

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

When I try to access my Shopify App in localhost, it undergoes an auth process but then I get redirect to this address: https://undefined/admin/oauth/authorize...

Does anyone know why this happens? I followed [this tutorial](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react) if that helps

Comment: Can you show your redirecturi?

Comment: Check if the shop address exists or not on the page.

Comment: @RyanDawkes, have you been able to resolve this? I'm running into the same isue...

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me as well when I just did the tutorial. This is likely an auth problem.

In my case I didn't put the `SHOPIFY_API_KEY` and `SHOPIFY_API_SECRET` in apostrophes

so instead of:

```
SHOPIFY_API_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SHOPIFY_API_SECRET=shpss_xxxxxxxxxx
```

You have to type:

```
SHOPIFY_API_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
SHOPIFY_API_SECRET="shpss_xxxxxxxxxx"
```